# How to fix custom add menu page preventing media library from loading

Tags: customization, media-library, admin-menu

**functions.php**

```
require get_parent_theme_file_path( '/inc/option-admin-page.php' );
```

**option-admin-page.php**

```
function admin_page(){
    add_menu_page('menu page','Option Panel','administrator','admin_option_slug','admin_adjustment','', 22);    
    add_submenu_page('admin_option_slug','reservation_title','reservation page','administrator','reservation_slug','reservation_subpage');  
    add_submenu_page('admin_option_slug','contact_title','contact page','administrator','contact_slug','contact_subpage');  

}
 add_action('admin_menu', 'admin_page');
function admin_adjustment(){
echo '<h1 style="text-align:center;">This page is for the Admin menu page Option </h1>';?>
<?php  } ?>

      <!-- reservation page -->
 <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/reservation', 'menu' ); ?> 


    <!-- contact page -->
  <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/contact', 'menu' ); ?>
```

[image]

I have this custom menu page  and sub menu page

Both add_menu_page and add_sub_menu page are working this contains:

reservation page and contact page

Somehow it preventing Media library from loading the images, it just keep on loading, I found out the custom add_menu_page preventing it from loading the media library, Any solution for this?

Comment: Show us some errors, either on PHP level or your browser console.

Comment: it does not have any error from console,If you click media the icon beside bulk select just keep on loading

Comment: Something might be breaking in the Ajax callback. You could enable debug to log file using `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` in your `wp-config.php` and then read that log file. https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: yeah i found some error and fix it somehow nothing change.i'll update the post

Comment: Im confuse when i comment out the require get_parent_theme_file_path( '/inc/option-admin-page.php' );  in function.php it somehow fix which means part of option-admin-page.php causing the problem, and when I comment out all inside the option-admin-page.php it does not fix

Comment: Or the path is wrong.

Comment: I think not it will display error and somehow the debug does not display any error anymore.

Comment: I also notice
 When i upload image it display error uploading but the image was uploaded
the grid for image is not working but the list is perfectly fine.